# jquery datatable has static width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datatable

I use datatable for display patient information. All's been fine. But I've met difficulties when tried to make table responsive. I've seen that table always has a static width. I've tried a lot of options like bAutoWidth: false, and bootstrap, but it doesn't work.  My table is

```
 <table id="Enrolled_Patients" class="responsive display table table-striped table-bordered table-hover tablerow-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th class="hidden-480">Subscriber ID</th>
                                        <th>Patient Name</th>
                                        <th class="hidden-480">City</th>
                                        <th>State</th>
                                        <th>Provider ID</th>
                                        <th>Balance</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th class="hidden-480">Last Update</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody></tbody>
                            </table>
```

code in knockout model

```
self.table = $('#Enrolled_Patients').dataTable({
            "iDisplayLength": 50,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": vm.url_list,
            "aaSorting": [[7, "desc"]],
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                null,
                null,
                null,
                null,
                { "sSortDataType": "dom-text", "sType": "currency" },
                null,
                null
            ],
            "fnServerData":
                function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < self.filterStatus.length; i++) {
                        aoData.push({ name: "status", value: self.filterStatus[i] });
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < self.filterCity.length; i++) {
                        aoData.push({ name: "city", value: self.filterCity[i] });
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < self.filterEmail.length; i++) {
                        aoData.push({ name: "email", value: self.filterEmail[i] });
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < self.filterState.length; i++) {
                        aoData.push({ name: "state", value: self.filterState[i] });
                    }
                    aoData.push({ name: "balanceFrom", value: self.balanceFrom });
                    aoData.push({ name: "balanceTo", value: self.balanceTo });
                },
            "fnPreDrawCallback": function (a) {
                var data = a.aoData;
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    var d = data[i]._aData;
                    d[1] = self.getNameHtml(d[0], d[1]);
                    d[6] = self.getStatusHtml(d[5], d[7] == "true");
                }
            }
        });
```

I use jquery.dataTables.min.js, jquery.dataTables-cust.min.js and  dataTables.responsive.min.js, datatables.responsive.css

So does anybody know how I can fix this?

Comment: If you're using all this and the table has a hardcoded width of 100%, I suspect the table's _container_ not to be responsive.

Comment: It doesn't depend on this attribute. The table has static size with both coded width and without it.

Comment: I'm very curious to see this. Do you have a preview URL, like a JSfiddle or something?